# Custom Pod Development for Adobe Livecycle

Tags: apache-flex, adobe, livecycle, lccs

I'm trying to create a poll pod for my LCCS Flex application but I know little about custom pod development. Yesterday I was looking at a good thread at [Adobe Forums](http://forums.adobe.com/community/livecycle/lccs) but it's down until Monday.

I googled a bit but couldn't find much info. Could you please guide me to a good tutorial or a knowledge base?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I've copied the Chat poll which comes with LCCS SDK. And used it as a template to create my own pod.